# An exception in z3

Tags: exception, warnings, z3

there
When I got unsat cores from a smtlib2 instance, I split them as an clause such as(not (>=::Int x1)).And then I tried to add the clause to the z3 to solve again.But the problems happened after being complied.

> WARNING: invalid function application, sort mismatch on argument at position 1
>   WARNING: (define not Bool Bool) applied to: (not (<= 0::Int x6)) of sort Bool

```
expr F = to_expr(ctx,f);
solver s(ctx);`
expr_vector todo(c);
vector<expr> u;
todo.push_back(F);
while (!todo.empty()) {
    expr current = todo.back();
    todo.pop_back();
    if (current.decl().decl_kind() == Z3_OP_AND) {
         for (unsigned i = 0; i < current.num_args(); i++) {
             u.push_back(current.arg(i));
          }
    }
}
for(i=0;i<u.size();i++){
    expr r = to_expr(ct.,Z3_mk_not(ctx,u[i]));
    s.add(r);
}
if(s.check() == sat){
    model m = s.get_model();
}else if(s.check() == unsat){
    expr_vector core = s.unsat_core();
}
```

Could you please help me out?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Please consider deleting the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783622/how-to-solve-these-z3-warnings. It is the same question.

Answer (score 2):

You have not provided the full example. So, it is hard to be precise. My guess is that you are mixing expressions from different Z3 contexts. The following piece of code is very suspicious:

```
solver s(ctx);
expr_vector todo(c);
```

It seems you have two Z3 contexts: `ctx` and `c`.
Expressions and formulas from one context can't be used into a different context. We have to translate them from one context to another (API: `Z3_translate`). This is an "advanced" feature. Most users don't need multiple contexts. I strongly suggest you use a single context.

Moreover, it seems you are trying to "glue" code fragments from different existing posts available here at Stackoverflow. However, the resultant code seems strange.
You are essentially getting a formula `f`, extracting its conjuncts in the `while`-loop, and then asserting the negation of each of them in the `for`-loop. That is, if `f` is the formula

```
A and B and C
```

Your program is asserting the following literals in the solver `s`: `(Not A)`, `(Not B)` and `(Not C)`.
Is that what you really want?

Why do you use two-loops? You can assert the negations in the `while`-loop, and avoid the auxiliary vector `u`.

Another issue, you invoke `check` without providing assumptions. So, the `unsat_core` method will return the empty vector. Please take a look in the unsat-core examples in the file `examples/c++/example.cpp` in the Z3 distribution.

Keep in mind that Z3 has APIs for managed languages such as Python and .Net. They are much easier to use than C++. We have several tutorial for the [Z3 Python API](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorial/guide).

Comment: Getting Unsat cores and extracting formulas from its conjuncts, then call z3 solver putting one negative formula to solve again. But once adding formula to the z3 solver usings.add(!formula) , the warnings have happened. I'm thinking the reason is the z3 solver cannot read the formulas again which are extracted from conjuncts. Because the original formulas in the conjuncts recorded such as (= x2 (* 6::Int x4), but after extracted which have been changed as (= x2 *( 6 x4)). Is that probably reason?